# fadeIn / FadeOut overlapping divs with bootstrap (CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Fairly new to bootstrap.. I want two divs to overlap each other with different content and the links below toggling them respectively.

However I can't seem to get divs positioned correctly to allow them to fadeIn/Out on top of each other and have the buttons/link below not move.

Here's a jsFiddle. I can't seem to get my head around which selector needs what position without messing up the bootstrap code. https://jsfiddle.net/karlt/8zdotv7o/4/

```js
$(".toggle-people").on('click', function() {
  $(".people").fadeIn(1000);
  $(".projects").fadeOut(1000);
});

$(".toggle-projects").on('click', function() {
  $(".people").fadeOut(1000);
  $(".projects").fadeIn(1000);
});
```

```css
.people,
.projects {
  text-align: center;
}
.projects {
  background-color: #46f2e6;
}
.people {
  display: none;
  background-color: #e56767;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">


  <div class="row">
    <div class="projects">
      <p>Project 1, Project 2, Project 3, Project, Project</p>
    </div>

    <div class="people">
      <p>Name 1, Name 2, Name 3, Name 4 , Name 5</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row text-center">

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <a class="toggle-people">People</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <a class="toggle-projects">Projects<a/>
    </div>
     
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Wrap your `.people` and `.projects` in a div.

2) Give `position:relative` to this wrapper.

3) Give `position:absolute` to `.projects` and `.people`.

Why?

Because when you give `position:absolute` to a div it will position with respect to a parent div having `position`  or else body if no such parent is found.

So it is safe to give `position:relative` to a wrapper.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8zdotv7o/6/).

Answer (score 1):

I updated your fiddle with a few changes to get the effect you are talking about.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8zdotv7o/5/)

Basically I used `position:absolute` to get them to sit in the same area. Hope it helps.
However this isn't a perfect response because absolute positioning takes the elements out of sequence of the other elements in your DOM.

Answer (score 1):

you can also keep the same design and add delay to it [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8zdotv7o/7/)

```
    $(".toggle-people").on('click', function() {
   $(".projects").fadeOut(1000);
    $(".people").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);

});

$(".toggle-projects").on('click', function() {
   $(".people").fadeOut(1000);
   $(".projects").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
});
```